# Running linux commnds on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, apktool

I am able to run certain Linux commands such as ls -l through my GUI using `subprocess` module. I also want to create a GUI that executes the `apktool` command on `tkinter` to disassemble apk files. How do i do it? I want the `apktool` command to work dynamically.

My code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import subprocess

def run():
    subprocess.run(["apktool", "d" ,"music.apk"])

root = Tk()
Button(root, text="Click to run 'ls -l'", command=run).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are already able to run commands and capture their output, right? What's the problem with running the `apktool` command?

Comment: i am able to run linux commands but i dont know how to run apktool command dynamically through my GUI

Comment: from tkinter import *
import subprocess

def run():
    subprocess.run(["apktool", "d" ,"music.apk"])

root = Tk()
Button(root, text="Click to run 'ls -l'", command=run).pack()
root.mainloop()
each time i run this code i will have to change the .apk filename. I dont want that. i want it to search for .apk filename and then run the command and disassemble that apk

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to select a file to open and then run the command accordingly?

Comment: Once i press the button the user should be able to view the apk files and select one among them and the command running in the subprocess will disassemble that particular selected  apk file by the user.

Comment: Try adding this: `from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename` then use this: `apk_filepath = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("APK files", "*.apk"), ("All files", "*.*")))`

Comment: subprocess.run(["apktool", "d" ,".apk"])

Comment: what would be my filename in the above line of code

Comment: Input file (.apk) was not found or was not readable. I am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import *
import subprocess

def run():
    apk_filepath = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("APK files", "*.apk"), ("All files", "*.*")))
    subprocess.run(["apktool", "d", apk_filepath])

root = Tk()
button = Button(root, text="Click to run 'ls -l'", command=run)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

It uses `tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename` to ask the user for the file.

Comment: @Prajwal Btw if you want to force the user to only choose `.apk` files change `filetypes=(("APK files", "*.apk"), ("All files", "*.*"))` to `filetypes=(("APK files", "*.apk"), )`

Comment: Also I want to create tabs in my GUI using tkinter dynamically instead off adding tab 1 , tab 2 to each and every function. How do I do that?

Comment: @Prajwal Are you sure your last comment wasn't meant for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67543794/how-do-i-create-tabs-in-tkinter-dynamically) question instead? :D

Comment: Yes it wasn't meant for this question. But I am stuck at that point from a long time. I am not getting how to create tabs dynamically