# How do I create tabs in tkinter dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have creatd a menu bar that has options open , edit and some more. The dropmenu in open says open file , save file and save as.
I want to design the GUI in such a way that when click open and choose the file , I want the file contents to be displayed in a new tab and when I click another option I want it to be displayed in another tab.
Can anybody help me with this?
[image]

```
    from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import font
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
from tkinter import ttk
import subprocess
import os

root = Tk()
root.title('Text-Editor')
root.resizable(width=True, height=True)
root.geometry("1400x660")



def new_file():
    my_text.delete("1.0",END)
    root.title('New File - TextEditor')
    status_bar.config(text="New File        ")

def open_file():
    my_text.delete("1.0",END)
    text_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title="Open file" , filetypes = (("APK Files","*.apk"),("all files","*.*")))
    name=text_file
    status_bar.config(text=f'{name}       ')
    name = name.replace("/", "")
    root.title(f'{name}-TextEditor')
    text_file = open(text_file,'r')
    stuff = text_file.read()
    my_text.insert(END , stuff)
    text_file.close()


def save_as_file():
    text_file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".*",initialdir="/",title="Save file",filetypes=(("Text files",".txt"),("All files",".*.*")))
    if text_file:
        name = text_file
        name = name.replace("/","")
        root.title(f'{name} Saved1-TextEditor')

        text_file = open(text_file,'w')
        text_file.write(my_text.get(1.0, END))

        text_file.close()


def get_path(p):
    p = p.split(".")
    p.pop()
    return ''.join(p)


apk_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",title = "Disassembling", filetypes=(("APK files","*.apk"),("All files","*.apk")))
gpath = get_path(apk_path) + "/AndroidManifest.xml"


def dis_file():
    
    subprocess.run(["apktool","d",apk_path])
    b = str(apkname(apk_path))
    command = "ls " + b + " >" + " a.txt"
    os.system(command)
    os.system("pwd > path.txt")
    file()
    

    
def perm_file():
    tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabcontrol)
    tabcontrol.add(tab1 , text = "Permissions")
    tabcontrol.pack(fill = "both" , expand = 1)
    with open(gpath,'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
    dom = parseString(data)
    nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName('uses-permission')
    l = Listbox(tab1,height=600,
        width=650,
        bg = "grey",
        activestyle="dotbox",
        font="Arial",
        fg="black")
    co = 0
    for c,node in enumerate(nodes):
        co+=1
        l.insert(c,node.getAttribute('android:name'))
    l.insert(0,f'Number of Permissions : {co}')

    l.pack()


def apkname(a):
    a = a.split("/")
    a = a[-1].split(".")
    return a[0]

def act_file():
    tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabcontrol)
    tabcontrol.add(tab2 , text = "Activity Names")
    tabcontrol.pack(fill = "both" , expand = 1)
    with open(gpath,'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
    dom = parseString(data)
    nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName('activity')
    l = Listbox(tab2, height=600,
        width=650,
        bg = "grey",
        activestyle="dotbox",
        font="Arial",
        fg="black")
    co = 0
    for c,node in enumerate(nodes):
        co += 1
        l.insert(c,node.getAttribute('android:name'))
    l.insert(0,f'Number of Activities : {co}')
    l.pack()

def inte_file():
    with open(gpath,'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
    dom = parseString(data)
    nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName('action')
    top = Toplevel()
    l = Listbox(top, height=600,
        width=650,
        bg = "grey",
        activestyle="dotbox",
        font="Arial",
        fg="black")
    top.geometry("700x250")
    co = 0
    for c,node in enumerate(nodes):
        co += 1
        l.insert(c,node.getAttribute('android:name'))
    l.insert(0,f'Number of Intent Actions : {co}')
    l.pack()

def intent_cat():
    with open(gpath,'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
    dom = parseString(data)
    nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName('category')
    top = Toplevel()
    l = Listbox(top, height=600,
        width=650,
        bg = "grey",
        activestyle="dotbox",
        font="Arial",
        fg="black")
    top.geometry("700x250")
    co = 0
    for c,node in enumerate(nodes):
        co += 1
        l.insert(c,node.getAttribute('android:name'))
    l.insert(0,f'Number of Intents Categories : {co}')
    l.pack()

def serv_file():
    with open(gpath,'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
    dom = parseString(data)
    nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName('service')
    top = Toplevel()
    l = Listbox(top, height=600,
        width=650,
        bg = "grey",
        activestyle="dotbox",
        font="Arial",
        fg="black")
    top.geometry("700x250")
    co = 0
    for c,node in enumerate(nodes):
        co += 1
        l.insert(c,node.getAttribute('android:name'))
    l.insert(0,f'Number of Services : {co}')
    l.pack()

def prov_file():
    with open(gpath,'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
    dom = parseString(data)
    nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName('provider')
    top = Toplevel()
    l = Listbox(top, height=600,
        width=650,
        bg = "grey",
        activestyle="dotbox",
        font="Arial",
        fg="black")
    top.geometry("700x250")
    co = 0
    for c,node in enumerate(nodes):
        co += 1
        l.insert(c,node.getAttribute('android:name'))
    l.insert(0,f'Number of providers : {co}')
    l.pack()

def recv_file():
    with open(gpath,'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
    dom = parseString(data)
    nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName('receiver')
    top = Toplevel()
    l = Listbox(top, height=600,
        width=650,
        bg = "grey",
        activestyle="dotbox",
        font="Arial",
        fg="black")
    top.geometry("700x250")
    co = 0
    for c,node in enumerate(nodes):
        co += 1
        l.insert(c,node.getAttribute('android:name'))
    l.insert(0,f'Number of Receivers : {co}')
    l.pack()

def app_file():
    with open(gpath,'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
    dom = parseString(data)
    nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName('manifest')
    top = Toplevel()
    l = Listbox(top, height=600,
        width=650,
        bg = "grey",
        activestyle="dotbox",
        font="Arial",
        fg="black")
    top.geometry("700x250")
    co = 0
    for node in nodes:
        co += 1
        l.insert(1,f'Package Name:{node.getAttribute("package")}')
        l.insert(2,f'compileSdkVersion:{node.getAttribute("android:compileSdkVersion")}')
        l.insert(3,f'compileSdkVersionCodename:{node.getAttribute("android:compileSdkVersionCodename")}')
        l.insert(4,f'XMLNS:{node.getAttribute("xmlns:android")}')
        l.insert(5,f'platformBuildVersionCode:{node.getAttribute("platformBuildVersionCode")}')
        l.insert(6,f'platformBuildVersionName:{node.getAttribute("platformBuildVersionName")}')

    l.insert(0,f'Count = {co}')
    l.pack()

def file():
    with open('/home/prajwal/Downloads/a.txt','r') as f:
        data = f.read()
    a = data.split('\n')
    top = Toplevel()
    l = Listbox(top, height=600,
        width=650,
        bg = "grey",
        activestyle="dotbox",
        font="Arial",
        fg="black")
    top.geometry("700x250")
    l.insert(0,"Extracted Files:")
    for c,i in enumerate(a):
        l.insert(c+1,i) 
    l.pack()

my_frame = Frame(root)
my_frame.pack(pady=3)

tabcontrol = ttk.Notebook(my_frame)

text_scroll = Scrollbar(root)
text_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT , fill=Y)

my_text = Text(root , font=("Arial", 16), selectbackground="yellow", selectforeground="black", undo=True, yscrollcommand=text_scroll.set)
my_text.pack(fill=BOTH , expand=1)

text_scroll.config(command=my_text.yview)

my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu)

file_menu = Menu(my_menu , tearoff = False)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="File" , menu = file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="New",command=new_file) 
file_menu.add_command(label="Open",command=open_file)
file_menu.add_command(label="Save")
file_menu.add_command(label="Save As",command=save_as_file)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command = root.quit)

edit_menu = Menu(my_menu , tearoff=False)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="Edit" , menu = edit_menu)
edit_menu.add_command(label="Cut")
edit_menu.add_command(label="Copy")
edit_menu.add_command(label="Paste")
edit_menu.add_command(label="Undo")
edit_menu.add_command(label="Redo")

dis_menu = Menu(my_menu , tearoff = False)
my_menu.add_cascade(label = "APK",menu=dis_menu)
dis_menu.add_command(label = "Disassemble", command = dis_file)
dis_menu.add_command(label = "Show Permissions", command = perm_file)
dis_menu.add_command(label = "Show Activity Names", command = act_file)
dis_menu.add_command(label = "Show Intents", command = inte_file)
dis_menu.add_command(label = "Show Intent Category", command = intent_cat)
dis_menu.add_command(label = "Show Services", command = serv_file)
dis_menu.add_command(label = "Show Providers", command = prov_file)
dis_menu.add_command(label = "Show Recievers", command = recv_file)
dis_menu.add_command(label = "Show App Info", command = app_file)

status_bar = Label(root, text='Ready        ', anchor = E)
status_bar.pack(fill=X ,side=BOTTOM , ipady =5)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Have you looked at using `ttk.Notebook`?

Comment: What do you mean by *dynamically add tabs*? Doesn't your open button in your menu add the new tab?

Comment: Can you please edit your question so it includes your code for the menu and your tab adding code?

Comment: To add tabs to your program, you will need to restructure your code. I recommend using classes or at least a list of all of the `tkinter.Text` widgets that you will have open. `new_file` should create a new tab with its own `tkinter.Text` widget

Comment: Just a quick question: Are you familiar with classes/object oriented programming?

Comment: The above code does not give any errors but the functionalities such as menu bar or any other options are not visible. Can anybody help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the code You want (simple example):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Menu, Text
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile


text_list = []


def add_tab(parent, contents, name):
    text = Text()
    text_list.append(text)
    text = text_list[len(text_list) - 1]
    
    parent.add(text, text=name)
    text.insert('end', contents)


def open_file():
    file = askopenfile(filetypes=[('Text file', '*.txt')])

    if file:
        add_tab(notebook, file.read(), file.name.split('/')[-1])


root = Tk()

menu_bar = Menu(root)

file_menu = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label='Open', command=open_file)

root.config(menu=menu_bar)

notebook = Notebook(width=700, height=500)
notebook.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

There is not much to say about this, the only thing to add is that when using tabs and text You need to somehow store the index of text widget so that You can always access it (to perform actions on that specific text widget) (and I can tell that it won't be easy) but so far this works and does what You asked for.

Sources:

- [`ttk.Notebook` docs](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Notebook.html)
- [`pack()` docs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_pack.htm) (tho don't forget that there are other layout methods too)

Comment: ill try it and will get back to you

Comment: I don't think OP is very familiar with classes/object oriented programming. Also wouldn't it be better to move `askopenfile(filetypes=[('Text file', '*.txt')])` inside a new method in the `Tab` class?

Comment: I started writing an answer but OP couldn't modify it to his/her needs because a lack of understanding of how python classes work. You can freely use it if you want ([here](https://pastebin.com/Zf7vbhDE))

Comment: @TheLizzard oh, well I read that OP was familiar and since OP's given code was using classes I thought some basic understanding there was. About that `askopenfile` well I just moved it there since `open_file` was called from the main window and the function name was `open_file` so it kinda suited it, but yeah I guess it would make sense to place it in `Tab` class and maybe add an argument for specifying what to do with tab, like creating a new file or opening an existing one. In that case tho a few kwarg arguments could also be added since in such case say contents may not necessary be needed

Comment: @Matiiss Look at the revisions history for the question (before OP edited it). It doesn't use classes. Also I will undelete my answer so you can look at it. It implements a basic editor with save/saveas/open functions and adding new tabs. You can use any/all of my code from there. The problem is that OP doesn't know how to implement the rest of the functionality.

Comment: Edited my code so that it does not use any classes tho now it is crucial to keep track of index (could actually use dictionaries instead of a list but it's up to You) so take a look BUT **I really suggest You take a look at some OOP tutorials** for example [this tutorial series by Corey Schafer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDa-Z5JzLYM&list=PL-osiE80TeTsqhIuOqKhwlXsIBIdSeYtc) and You don't even need to watch all of it just some of the first videos + they are not too long.

Comment: The functionalities such as open,save,save as are all working fine in my code as well. But the other functions such as disassemble and so on . i am not getting how to implement them because they involve subprocess module , OS modules  , listboxes and i dont know how these work with classes/ OOP.

Comment: I made code so that it does not use classes, but which part do You exactly don't understand about using OOP, please give me an example of one thing You have trouble with and what exactly do You not understand about that thing and how to implement it. But really just watch a tutorial (for example the one I gave in my previous comment)

Comment: In your code in add_tab(notebook) in open_file() ,instead of notebook can i not use root or frame. Because using notebook on top a root window is looking a little weird in the GUI.

Comment: And coming to the oop part, the code i have edited above has functions such as dis_file() and more functions after that.  I am not able to understand how to use OOP for those functions. Even without classes i am not understanding what to pass as master in listbox and how to pass the add_tab () functions in those functions. if you can have a look at it and help me , it would be grateful

Comment: Did You read what that notebook as an argument does? like later in the `add_tab()` function what exactly is the notebook? it is an instance of `Notebook` soo... if You replace `notebook` to `root` what will happen? it will try to call `Tk().add()` which isn't a method for `Tk()` so no You cannot do that, what You can do is for example replace the `Text()` to frame if You want to have notebook tab as a Frame or You can put Notebook in a frame itself. The best way would be if You just tested and put `root` instead of `notebook` in there and see what happens.

Comment: yeah i tried that and it said tk.add isnt a method. so what other option do i have to display it on the main window rather than notebook window?

Comment: Wait so do You want tabs or not? because if You want tabs You have two options: create a custom "Notebook" type thing or use `ttk.Notebook` (as in my code), otherwise what do You want? I am a bit confused because I understood You want to have tabs so what issue do You have?

Comment: i do want tabs but i dont want the contents to be displayed on the notebook  type of frame. I want the tabs to be displayed on the root window instead of a customed window on the root window

Comment: i checked ttk.Notebook but i dont how to use them dynamically as in i created a seperate tab in each of the functions as tab1,tab2,tab3 which is of no use and so on. Using ttk.Notebook how do i do it dynamically?

Comment: To the earlier comment: so You want to create Your own custom "Notebook" that will store its contents on the `root`, correct? If so why do You need them to be on the `root`. To the later comment: the code above adds new tabs dinamically: that is: every time You use `open_file` a new tab is added.

Comment: The thing is i am getting a notebook frame of (height x weight) overlapping on my root window and its contents are being displayed on the root window of certain size and its looking a bit weird. Thats why i want the contents to be displayed on the root window which will look better although i want tabs as well.

Comment: Coming to the later comment:- Yes its getting added dynamically but i am not understanding how i should pass the add_tab() method to other functions such as dis_file and so on. Can you just have look at the code above that i have mentioned and look at those functions and help how i should pass the add_tab() method.

Comment: it would be great if You could include some picture of how exactly does it look to You (edit Your post or add a link here but better if You directly add screenshots to post) otherwise I can try creating some custom "Notebook" but... I don't know, will see

Comment: btw in this case `add_tab` can't be directly applied to all cases, you could add another argument that specifies what kind of tab is being created and then just use `if/elif` statements to create the accroding tab or instead just create multiple functions like `add_tab_open` , `add_tab_new` and so on

Comment: it would be great if you could show me what you just mentioned above regarding if/elif or multiple functions part and coming to the screenshot part ill do that.

Comment: I think I already explained what I meant: in case of using an argument it could look like this: `def add_tab(*args, type)` and then in the function do like `if type == 'open':`  and under that `if ` place all the functions that would create a new tab and place file contents in it (all functions in the given code) and then create for example a `elif type == 'new':`  and under this statement place code that would create a new empty tab. if using multiple functions the same: for example in `add_tab_open` would be all the code I provided, in `add_tab_new` would be code to create new empty tab

Comment: okay will try that, i have added the screenshot please have a look at it

Comment: did you have a look at the other functions such as dis_file() and all the other methods after that? how do i use add_tab for those function is what i want to know

Comment: wow, so first of `width` and `height` arguments are not necessary for `ttk.Notebook` ok, so You might as well just use `notebook = Notebook(root)` (I actually forgot to specify the master argument in the code above) and then use `notebook.pack()` with arguments such as `fill='x'` which are basic tkinter stuff like this for example `notebook.pack(fill='x')` which does what it says btw (for Your case try `notebook.pack(fill='both')`). Also take a look at the docs I provided in my answer about `ttk.Notebook` and here is a source about [`pack()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_pack.htm)

Comment: about other functions: this question is more related to creating tabs dinamically so it is a bit off-topic and it is getting a bit filled up here so it probably would be better if You asked another question regarding other issues.

Comment: i am still not getting it the way i want , tried everything i could

Comment: ok try using `notebook.pack(fill='both', expand=True)` this should cover all the space if notebook is the only widget on root except for Menu

Comment: There are 2 frames that are getting displayed now I don't know why. I'll add the screen shot as to how it looks

Comment: i have added the screenshot

Comment: even when i put notebook(root) i am still getting the output same as shown in the screenshot

Comment: @Matiiss  can you help me with this?

Comment: which function exactly is causing this to happen?

Comment: When I click open itself that's happening. The same function that you gave. I removed the scroll bar widget also and checked

Comment: @matiiss any idea? I have seen oop tutorial videos as well. So even with classes if you can tell me how to create tabs dynamically. That would be helpful

Comment: in Your given code, in the `open_file` function there is no mention of `tabcontrol` which is Your `ttk.Notebook` instance so I am confused ok, and I don't understand how You could have gotten that other thing, ok? great, so the thing is that You apparently lack the basics of `tkinter`. So the issue at hand is that when You use `open` in Your menu, You just open the file and display the contents in a Text widget whose parent is `root`, so obviously when You open a tab in Your notebook since it is listed higher it will get packed first and above the `Text` widget, put that `Text` in `tabcontrol`

Comment: And what if I remove the tabcontrol instance? Or do u mean I should put it as tabcontrol = ttk.Notebook(my_text)

Comment: Dude, in my example what do I do? I use `add` method so You should do in Your code. Just create a `Text` instance and then `tabcontrol.add(text_instance)` and don't pack that `text_instance`, ok? Just add it to the Notebook, leave the rest alone.

Comment: Ahh nope not understanding it. Anyways I'll try it with classes and objects.

Comment: It will literally be the same thing, You will still have to use `add` method if using `Notebook`, well at least I tried, good luck with coding then. if You have questions related to this issue You can ask

Comment: In my code I already have a text instance as my_text. So below that I have my tabcontrol instance. So what you told me is to do tabcontrol.add(my_text) below my tabcontrol instance. Am I right?

Comment: If You look at my code, what do You see? there is a function right? in that function I have defined a `Text` instance: `text = Text()`, right? and then somewhere under that I have put `parent.add(text, text=name)`, correct? so what happens then? I have defined a text instance inside a function and right after that I add that text instance to my `ttk.Notebook` instance, correct? do You understand? take a look at how my `add_tab()` function works, ok, that is how You should add a tab when using Your `open_file()` function, is that clear?

Comment: Ok so I should create a text instance in my open_file() and then do tabcontrol.add(text instance) and then call add_tab(tabcontrol) correct?

Comment: Yes that is what I think You should do, tho there is no need to call `add_tab(tabcontrol)` because You would have already added the tab

Comment: Okay will try that

Comment: So this means if i want to add a tab for each option in my menu bar i will have to add seperate text instance and do tabcontrol.add(text_instance) to each function?

Comment: If You want to have only a text widget in that tab then yes, but You also should store those instances in a list or sth

Comment: umm why is it required to store it in a list?

Comment: it is not required, You just have to keep a reference if You want to use those widgets, I mean You will still be able to write to them and all, but You won't be able to get the text from those widgets and all that, that is of course if You have multiple same widgets

Comment: And if I have to name that particular tab say I click permission and the tab has to be opened with permission name or say I click new then the tab has to be opened with a name new tab. Do I have to give tabcontrol.add(text_instance , text = new tab) and so on for each function?

Comment: not for each function, only those who are supposed to open new tabs. Also take a look at docs I have linked in my answer about Notebook if You have questions regarding its methods

Comment: @Matiis i want to close the tabs just like how we close it in a browser. How do I create that functionality?

Comment: could YOu please ask another question and maybe link it here so I can take a look (also show what You have tried) because this is getting rather lengthy. two methods come right to mind: make Your own tab class or add a button that when clicked will get the current tab that is in focus and delete it, however it won't be as similar to browsers (it will be just one button somewhere in a corner or sth). EDIT: another option would be to track position of mouse, a bit conmplicated and may not look as good. Maybe something like `compound` option could support this better, tho check the docs I gave

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog


class Tab:
    def __init__(self, notebook:ttk.Notebook):
        self.filename = None
        self.notebook = notebook

        self.text_widget = tk.Text(self.notebook)
        self.text_widget.bind("<Control-o>", self.open)
        self.text_widget.bind("<Control-s>", self.save)
        self.text_widget.bind("<Control-Shift-S>", self.saveas)
        self.notebook.add(self.text_widget, text="The tab name")

    def open(self, _=None):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        if filename != "":
            with open(filename, "r") as file:
                data = file.read()
            self.text_widget.delete("0.0", "end")
            self.text_widget.insert("end", data)
            self.filename = filename
        return "break"

    def save(self, _=None):
        if self.filename is None:
            self.saveas()
        else:
            self._save()
        return "break"

    def saveas(self, _=None):
        filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
        if filename == "":
            return "break"
        self.filename = filename
        self._save()

    def _save(self):
        assert self.filename is not None, "self.filename shouldn't be None"
        data = self.text_widget.get("0.0", "end")
        with open(self.filename, "w") as file:
            file.write(data)


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.new_tab_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="New tab", command=self.add_new_tab)
        self.new_tab_button.pack()
        self.open_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Open file", command=self.open_file)
        self.open_button.pack()
        self.save_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Save file", command=self.save_file)
        self.save_button.pack()
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.root)
        self.notebook.pack()
        self.tabs = []

    def add_new_tab(self):
        tab = Tab(self.notebook)
        self.tabs.append(tab)

    def get_current_tab(self):
        # This code gets the currently selected tab
        idx = self.notebook.index(self.notebook.select())
        tab = self.tabs[idx]
        return tab

    def open_file(self):
        tab = self.get_current_tab()
        tab.open() # Call `open` on the tab

    def save_file(self):
        tab = self.get_current_tab()
        tab.save() # Call `save` on the tab

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

It creates an `App` object which creates new `Tab` objects each time the `"New tab"` button is pressed. It also supports opening files. Adding the rest of the functionality should be easy.

Comment: ahh nope not getting how to add the rest of the functionality

Comment: @Prajwal I added `save` and `saveas` to my answer. What are you having problems with? Which functionality is the problematic one?

Comment: i have edited my code....can you please go through it and let me know where have in gone wrong

Comment: @Prajwal Look at a object oriented programming tutorial. Most of your code needs restructuring.

Comment: can you please help me with it? i actually dont have time to look at tutorial of object oriented programming